# Avoiding serialization in distributed EHCache

Tags: serialization, jms, ehcache

Is there a way to not use serialization and still use the EHCache disktore.
I have nested objects , which are not serializable, which have to cached in a distributed ehcache.
I can use JMS, to avoid serialization, and still achieve cache replication. But is there a way to avoid serialization to use the diskstore as well? 
Why isn't there any similar support for diskstore..something like xml serialization maybe.

Answer (score 1):

http://ehcache.org/features.html#Supports_Object_or_Serializable_caching

"As of ehcache-1.2 there is an API for Objects in addition to the one for Serializable. Non-serializable Objects can use all parts of Ehcache except for DiskStore and replication. If an attempt is made to persist or replicate them they are discarded and a WARNING level log message emitted."